# Decomposition of Algebraic Numbers into Sets of Real and Rational Numbers

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, analysis

Show that a real number $\alpha$ is algebraic of degree at most $n$ if and only if there are real numbers $\{a_1, a_2, ..., a_n\}$ such that for every $k \in \mathbb{N}$ there exist rational numbers $\{b_{1,\space k}, ..., b_{n, \space k}\}$ such that $\alpha^k = a_1b_{1,\space k} + ... + a_nb_{n,\space k}$.

There are two hints: For the forward assertion use the Euclidean Algorithm and for the reverse use linear algebra.

I have been staring at this problem for hours and all of my attempts have led me nowhere. I would appreciate any suggestions on how to proceed or any other references.

One failed attempt: I tried to argue that $\alpha^k$ = $(\alpha^{n})^{k/n}$ and from here I tried to exponentiate $p(\alpha) - \alpha^n$ and proceed inductively. I ended up with a mess and did not think it would get me anywhere

Comment: Where did you encounter the question, and hints?    Can you include the attempts, even if they failed?

Comment: I added one of my attempts that I thought would work. I believe the problem is from Tao's Analysis textbook.

Comment: Harry Xi That's great.  I've retracted my close vote.

Answer (score 2):

For the first direction, let me give you an example. Suppose $\alpha = 1 + \sqrt[3] 2$. Then $(\alpha - 1)^3 - 2 = 0$. So we have

$$ \alpha^3 - 3 \alpha^2 + 3 \alpha - 3 = 0. $$

Thus

$$ \alpha^3 = 3 \cdot \alpha^0 - 3 \cdot \alpha^1 + 3 \cdot \alpha^2. \tag{1} $$

Now I multiply both sides by $\alpha$ to obtain

$$ \alpha^4 = 3 \cdot \alpha^1 - 3 \cdot \alpha^2 + 3 \cdot \alpha^3. $$

Using $(1)$ we write this as

$$ \alpha^4 = 9 \cdot \alpha^0 - 6 \alpha^1 + 6 \alpha^2. $$

Likewise, if we multiply this by $\alpha$ and apply $(1)$ we obtain

$$ \alpha^5 = 18 \cdot \alpha^0 - 9 \cdot \alpha^1 + 12 \cdot \alpha^2. $$

Repeating this, we observe that we can always write

$$ \alpha^k = b_{0,k} \cdot \alpha^0 + b_{1,k} \cdot \alpha^1 + b_{2,k} \cdot \alpha^2 $$

for some rational numbers $b_{0,k}, b_{1,k}, b_{2,k}$.

Try using the polynomial division (the Euclidean Algorithm) to make this precise.

---

For the second direction, show that $1, \alpha, \alpha^2, \dots, \alpha^n$ are linearly dependent over $\mathbf{Q}$ by showing that they belong to a $\mathbf{Q}$-vector space of dimension at most $n$. What does linear dependence tell you?

Comment: I think I understand the forward direction now. For the reverse direction should I be representing $\alpha^k = \alpha^k = a_1b_{1,\space k} + ... + a_nb_{n,\space k}$ as a vector of size $n$ of the form $(a_1b_{1,\space k}, ..., a_nb_{n,\space k})$?

Comment: How would we get $\alpha^2$?

Comment: @AlJebr $\alpha^2 = 0\cdot \alpha^0 + 0 \cdot \alpha^1 + 1 \cdot \alpha^2$

Comment: @HarryXi Tuples are suggestive of a basis. That is, if $v_1,\dots,v_n$ are a basis then the vector $c_1v_1 + \cdots + c_nv_n$ is represented by the tuple $(c_1,\dots,c_n)$. You don't need to think of tuples to do this, just think of $a_1,\dots,a_n$ as being the vectors and the rational numbers $b_{i,j}$ as being the scalars.

Comment: @TrevorGunn I think I understand now. So essentially $\alpha^k$ is a vector in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and the vectors $1, \alpha, ..., \alpha^n$ are a set of $n+1$ vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$, therefore they must be linearly dependent, so there exist nonzero $a_0, a_1, ..., a_n$ such that $a_0 + a_1\alpha +...+ a_n \alpha^n =0$ where $a_n = 1$.

Comment: If $\alpha$ is a root, we have $p(\alpha)=0$. So $\alpha^n= a_0+a_1\alpha^1+\cdots+a_{n-1}\alpha^{n-1}$. Can't we just iterate from here?

Comment: Also, where does the Euclidean algorithm come into play? It seems like my comment above would take of one direction.

Comment: @AlJebr You don't have to use the Euclidean Algorithm; you can use induction. The argument in mind is to use the Euclidean Algorithm between $x^n$ an the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ This gives $\alpha^n = q(\alpha)p(\alpha) + r(\alpha) = r(\alpha)$ with $\deg r < \deg p$.

Comment: @HarryXi $\alpha^k$ is not a vector in $\mathbf{R}^n$; it is a vector in $\mathbf{R}$ viewed as a $\mathbf{Q}$-vector space. More specifically, it is an element of the subspace spanned by the $n$ vectors $a_1,\dots,a_n$.